# How to display pandas dataframe in tabular format using python and AngularJS

Tags: python, pandas, angularjs, flask

I am developing a web-based dashboard, where I am using python as backend technology and AngularJS as Front-End Technology. If anyone could help me to achieve this would be appreciated as I am a beginner in development.

Thank You for your advance support.

I am getting results but it's in JSON format not in a tabular format; not sure why I am not getting the expected result.

Below is the Code where in the backend I am importing Excel sheet and converting it into pandas data frame

```py
# app.py

from flask import Flask, jsonify
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    # read example Excel file into Pandas dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')
    
    # convert dataframe to JSON and return
    return jsonify(df.to_dict(orient='records'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start Flask server
    app.run(debug=True)
```

here below is the code which i am using for front End

```
#index.html

<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>My Dashboard</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
                <td>{{row['Column 1']}}</td>
                <td>{{row['Column 2']}}</td>
                <td>{{row['Column 3']}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('/data').then(function(response) {
                $scope.data = response.data;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your specific question/issue? Please show the response JSON.